# Reading file until line has a specific value

Tags: java

I have an csv file with following schema:

```
HEADER1
entry1
entry2
HEADER2
entry3
entry4
...
```

The headers are dividing entries of different objects. I created a BufferedReader and two while loops and I would like to iterate through the first while loop until the value of next line is equal to the value of HEADER2 (than I wanna exit this iteration and start a next one and create different objects). My problem is in writting this condition:

```
while ( !"MEETING_ROOMS".equals(line = reader.readLine())) || ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
```

this returns me an "illegal start of expression" error.

Comment: The brackets in that code are incorrect, `.equals(line = reader.readLine()))` should be `.equals(line = reader.readLine())`

Comment: The complete condition for while must be encapsulated in a bracket.
Instead of while(condition1) || (condition2) it should be while(condition1 || condition2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic of your `while` loop is off.  Try this version:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && !"MEETING_ROOMS".equals(line)) {
    // process line
}
```

The condition in the `while` loop first attempts to read a line.  Should it be not `null` then it applies an additional check to make sure the line is not `MEETING_ROOMS`.

You also had an unbalanced parentheses problem, but that goes away in my version.